# How do I get a list of table-like objects visible to duckdb in a python session?

Tags: python, pandas, duckdb

I like how duckdb lets me query DataFrames as if they were sql tables:

```py
df = pandas.read_parquet("my_data.parquet")
con.query("select * from df limit 10").fetch_df()
```

I also like how duckdb has metadata commands like `SHOW TABLES;`, like a real database. However, `SHOW TABLES;` doesn't show pandas DataFrames or other table-like objects.

my question is: does duckdb offer something like `SHOW TABLES;` that includes both (1) real database tables and (2) table-like objects (e.g. pandas DataFrames) and their schemas?

Thanks!

Comment: Last time I checked - you would need to register a view and then query `information_schema.columns` https://github.com/duckdb/duckdb/discussions/3623

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the different metadata table functions `duckdb_%` as referred [here](https://duckdb.org/docs/sql/duckdb_table_functions)

For an equivalent of `SHOW TABLES` and convert it as a pandas dataframe

```py
import duckdb

df = duckdb.sql("SELECT * FROM duckdb_tables;").df()
print(df.dtypes)

database_name             object
database_oid               int64
schema_name               object
schema_oid                 int64
table_name                object
table_oid                  int64
internal                    bool
temporary                   bool
has_primary_key             bool
estimated_size             int64
column_count               int64
index_count                int64
check_constraint_count     int64
sql                       object
dtype: object
```

Note : I'm using the latest version of duckDB v0.7.1

Comment: The link that is provided in this answer is gold.